# Batch string concatenation in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, concatenation, string-concatenation

I have a couple hundred of cells in Excel I would like to concatenate into a single string. Is there a simpler method of doing this than going through them one by one manually in order to type them into `CONCATENATE(A1, A2, ....)`?

`CONCATENATE(A1:A255)` does not work.

Comment: There are probably ways to do it using vb.

What you want to search for is "concatenate a RANGE in excel"

Comment: There are ways to do it without VBA as well: http://www.get-digital-help.com/2011/02/09/concatenate-a-cell-range-without-vba-in-excel/

Comment: Split and Join are two obvious functions missing from Excel. Very frustrating.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

*In a new tab, type A1 in cell A1,

*Type A2 in Cell A2

*Use fill series to complete the values in column A

*Type A1 in cell B1

- Use this forumal in cell B2

  =B1&","&A2
- Copy the formula down.

Copy and paste values to harvest the string of values you created.

```
A1  A1
A2  A1,A2
A3  A1,A2,A3
A4  A1,A2,A3,A4
A5  A1,A2,A3,A4,A5
A6  A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6
A7  A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7
A8  A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8
A9  A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9
A10 A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9,A10
```

Comment: this is a great dumbed down method that works beautifully, thanks

Comment: It's worth noting that the helper cells don't need to be adjacent to the cells you are concatenating. You can even put them on a separate worksheet, so as not to clutter things up.

Comment: To comma-separate the values, follow these instructions and use this as the formula in B2:
```=B1 & ", "","" ," & A2```

Comment: Amazing! Work great for me. Thanks

Comment: This is genius.

Answer (score 13):

Press `Alt-F11`, insert new module, paste code bellow.

```VB
Public Function concatRange(data As Range, Optional sep As String = "") As String
    Dim ret As String
    Dim sep2 As String
    ret = ""
    sep2 = ""

    For Each cell In data
        ret = ret & sep2 & cell.Value
        sep2 = sep
    Next cell

    concatRange = ret
End Function
```

Usage:

```
=concatRange(A8:D11;", ")    'OS with ; list separator
=concatRange(A8:D11,", ")    'OS with , list separator or in a macro code
```

or

```
=concatRange(A8:D11)
```

Answer (score 8):

See this blog post here: http://www.dullsharpness.com/2011/11/14/excel-vba-range-to-csv-range2csv-function/

You can use it like so, e.g. with a pipe delimiter:

```
=Range2Csv(A1:A255,"|")
```

Access your VBA editor using `Alt+F11` and drop it into a module.

Code excerpt is here:

```
Option Explicit
'**********************************************
'* PURPOSE: Concatenates range contents into a
'*          delimited text string
'*
'* FUNCTION SIGNATURE: Range2Csv(Range, String)
'*
'* PARAMETERS:
'*    Range  - the range of cells whose contents
'*             will be included in the CSV result
'*    String - delimiter used to separate values
'*             (Optional, defaults to a comma)
'*
'* AUTHOR: www.dullsharpness.com
'*
'* NOTES: [add'l notes removed for brevity]
'*
'**********************************************
Public Function Range2Csv(inputRange As Range, Optional delimiter As String)
  Dim concattedList As String 'holder for the concatted CSVs
  Dim rangeCell As Range      'holder cell used in For-Each loop
  Dim rangeText As String     'holder for rangeCell's text

  'default to a comma delimiter if none is provided
  If delimiter = "" Then delimiter = ","

  concattedList = ""          'start with an empty string

  'Loop through each cell in the range to append valid contents
  For Each rangeCell In inputRange.Cells

    rangeText = rangeCell.Value 'capture the working value

    'Only operate on non-blank cells (i.e. Length > 0)
    If Len(rangeText) > 0 Then
      'Strip any delimiters contained w/in the value itself
      rangeText = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(rangeText, delimiter, "")

      If (Len(concattedList) > 0) Then
        'prepend a delimiter to the new value if we
        'already have some list items
        concattedList = concattedList + delimiter + rangeText
      Else
        'else if the list is blank so far,
        'just set the first value
        concattedList = rangeText
      End If
    End If

  Next rangeCell

  'Set the return value
  Range2Csv = concattedList

End Function
```

Answer (score 6):

> concatenate(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10, a11, a12, a13, a14, a15, a16, a17, a18, a19, a20, a21, a22, a23, a24, a25, a26, a27, a28, a29, a30, a31, a32, a33, a34, a35, a36, a37, a38, a39, a40, a41, a42, a43, a44, a45, a46, a47, a48, a49, a50, a51, a52, a53, a54, a55, a56, a57, a58, a59, a60, a61, a62, a63, a64, a65, a66, a67, a68, a69, a70, a71, a72, a73, a74, a75, a76, a77, a78, a79, a80, a81, a82, a83, a84, a85, a86, a87, a88, a89, a90, a91, a92, a93, a94, a95, a96, a97, a98, a99, a100, a101, a102, a103, a104, a105, a106, a107, a108, a109, a110, a111, a112, a113, a114, a115, a116, a117, a118, a119, a120, a121, a122, a123, a124, a125, a126, a127, a128, a129, a130, a131, a132, a133, a134, a135, a136, a137, a138, a139, a140, a141, a142, a143, a144, a145, a146, a147, a148, a149, a150, a151, a152, a153, a154, a155, a156, a157, a158, a159, a160, a161, a162, a163, a164, a165, a166, a167, a168, a169, a170, a171, a172, a173, a174, a175, a176, a177, a178, a179, a180, a181, a182, a183, a184, a185, a186, a187, a188, a189, a190, a191, a192, a193, a194, a195, a196, a197, a198, a199, a200, a201, a202, a203, a204, a205, a206, a207, a208, a209, a210, a211, a212, a213, a214, a215, a216, a217, a218, a219, a220, a221, a222, a223, a224, a225, a226, a227, a228, a229, a230, a231, a232, a233, a234, a235, a236, a237, a238, a239, a240, a241, a242, a243, a244, a245, a246, a247, a248, a249, a250, a251, a252, a253, a254, a255)

PowerShell it!

```
"concatenate(a$((1..255) -join ', a'))" | clip
```

Open the text file copy and paste

["To quickly select cells you can press CTRL and click on cells you want to be included in the concatenate function.
Example,
Select a cell
Type =concatenate( in formula bar
Press and hold CTRL button and click cells to be included.
Release CTRL button
Type ) in formula bar and press Enter"](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2011/02/09/concatenate-a-cell-range-without-vba-in-excel/)

Answer (score 3):

This VBA function will concatenate the contents of cells, with an optional delimiter, if needed. Copy it into a standard module:

```
  Option Explicit

  Function Concat(CellRange As Range, Optional Delimiter As String) As String 
 ' this function will concatenate a range of cells and return the result as a single string
 ' useful when you have a large range of cells that you need to concatenate
 ' source: http://chandoo.org/wp/2008/05/28/how-to-add-a-range-of-cells-in-excel-concat/

  Dim retVal As String, dlm As String, cell As Range
  retVal = ""
  If Delimiter = Null Then
      dlm = ""
  Else
    dlm = Delimiter
  End If
  For Each cell In CellRange
      If CStr(cell.Value) <> "" And CStr(cell.Value) <> " " Then
          retVal = retVal & CStr(cell.Value) & dlm
      End If
  Next
  If dlm <> "" Then
      retVal = Left(retVal, Len(retVal) - Len(dlm))
  End If
  Concat = retVal
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

If your looking for a pure Excel approach (ie no VBA) then the method proposed by James Jenkins is best.
If you are happy using VBA then open up the VBA editor, add a new module, and add this code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function JoinText(cells As Variant,Optional delim_str As String) As String
    If cells.Columns.count < cells.Rows.count Then
       JoinText = Join(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(cells), delim_str)
    Else
       JoinText = Join(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(cells)), delim_str)
    End If
End Function
```

To open the VBA editor easily press Alt-F11.
To insert a module you right-click on the workbook listed in the 'Project' window.

The function is called from excel as follows:

```
=JoinText(A1:C1)
```

If you want to add a delimiter (eg comma):

```
=JoinText(A1:C1,",")
```

The purpose of using the transpose function is to turn the 2d array, 'cells', into a 1d array. The reson for this is that the VBA function Join only accepts a 1d array.
The reason for using two of them is if JoinText is looking at a row of cells (which is still just a 2d array) then the first call to transpose, transposes this 2d row array into a 2d column array, the second call turns it into a 1d array.

Answer (score 2):

My preferred method is to cut-and-paste the values into an editor that allows regular expressions, then I simply remove the tabs (or spaces) with a find and replace on my current selection.

You can also use this to insert commas, whitespace, or whatever you want.

It's a **ton** faster than typing `=concatenate(A1,",","A2",",",......)`

Comment: I like TextPad (freeware). 
-Hit F8 to pull up the "Find/Replace" dialog. 
-check the box 'use regular expression'
-FIND: \n    REPLACE: ,

Answer (score 1):

It isn't purely Excel, but there is an easy way to do this with Word.

1. Select the cells you want to concatenate and copy/paste them into Word. This creates a table.
2. Select the entire table.
3. Convert the table to text. Use paragraph marks (or something else that does not appear in your text) as separators.
4. Select all of the text.
5. Use Replace to remove the paragraph marks. (In the "Find what" box, enter ^p. Leave the "Replace with" box empty.)

Answer (score 1):

If you have Excel 2016, you can use an array formula:

Enter

> =concat(a1:a255)

into the cell, then press

> [ctrl]+[shift]+[enter]

Comment: No need to enter as an array formula actually, `CONCAT()` accepts an array input but returns a string, so you only have to hit enter

Answer (score 0):

where the values that you would like to concantenate start in row 2 column 3 of your sheet

```
Sub GOWN()
roww = 2
Do While cells(roww, 2) <> ""
    aa = cells(roww, 3)
    dd = dd & aa & ","
    roww = roww + 1
Loop
cells(roww + 1, 3) = dd
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Shamelessly copied from [this site](https://trumpexcel.com/concatenate-excel-ranges/):

> 1. Select the cell where you need the result.
> 2. Go to formula bar and enter ... "=A1:A5"
> 3. Select the entire formula and press F9 (this converts the formula into values).
> 4. Remove the curly brackets from both ends.
> 5. Add =CONCATENATE( to the beginning of the text and end it with a round bracket).
> 6. Press Enter.

What is particularly revelatory here is that when editing a formula, pressing F9 replaces the formula with the result of that formula. Where that's a range, it replaces it with a list of the contents of that range.

Answer (score -1):

Just add your deliminator in one concatenation:

```
=concatenate(A1, ",")
```

Then copy all the concatenations, paste them as Values. Then Copy those Values, paste them in a transposition. Then copy the Transposed values and paste them into a word editor. Do a find for the deliminator AND the space preceding the values and do a replace for JUST the deliminator. This should give you a concatenated string of all the values with a deliminator. This is much easier than other options.