# Concatenate 1000 cells of column to one cell at the bottom

Tags: excel

I want to combine text of 1000 cells of a particular column (say from A1 to A1000) to one single cell (say A1001), can anybody tell the macro for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [batch concatenate strings in excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15144816/batch-concatenate-strings-in-excel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following **UDF**

```
Public Function concat(r As Range) As String
    concat = ""
    For Each rr In r
        concat = concat & rr.Value
    Next rr
End Function
```

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

=concat(A1:A1000)

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

for specifics on UDFs

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: I pasted this on visual basic page and saved but no working as I tried to concatenate 2 selected cells where failed. Can you elaborate more or tell with example

Comment: What function did you put in the cell and what is it showing??

Comment: =concat(A1:A1000) this formula is not working despite I have saved UDF in VBE window

Comment: What is the formula displaying??

Comment: Formula desplayed is same as excel have i.e. =concatenate(.... not one which I have entered.

Answer (score -1):

```
=concatenate(A1:A1000)
```

As the formula in A1001

Comment: Sorry I haven't go excel on this machine to check it out - are all the values text values?

Comment: Sadly, `CONCATENATE` doesn't take accept a range. Rather it accepts it but only concatenates the first cell in the range.