# Lookup multiple values and return a single string

Tags: arrays, excel, lookup

I have found how to lookup multiple values and return them as a list (one value in one cell). But I need to display the found list in a single cell (as a string with break lines); preferably with a semicolon after each value.

For example:

Source list (one value - one cell):

```
A
A
B
B
B
C
```

Result (displayed in a single cell):

```
A;
B;
C;
```

Thank you!

Comment: As far as I can see you'll need VBA for this.

Comment: Are there any way to concatenate all array formula elements into one string? E. g. as far as I know we can sum all array elements.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to extract unique values and then concatenate those values.

When `a2:a7 = {a, a, b, b, b, c}`, type this at `b2` and hit `ctrl + shift + enter`.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$7,MATCH(SUM(COUNTIF(B$1:B1,$A$2:$A$7)),COUNTIF($A$2:$A$7,"<"&$A$2:$A$7),0)),"")
```

Then copy `b2` and paste it onto `b3:b7`. Now you have a list of unique values. This method is from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429899/getting-unique-values-in-excel-by-using-formulas-only).

Now that you have the list, you only have to join them. type this at `c2`.

```
=IF(B2="", "", B2&";"&CHAR(10))
&IF(B3="", "", B3&";"&CHAR(10))
&IF(B4="", "", B4&";"&CHAR(10))
&IF(B5="", "", B5&";"&CHAR(10))
&IF(B6="", "", B6&";"&CHAR(10))
&IF(B7="", "", B7&";"&CHAR(10))
```

See the picture.

[image]

I know this is ulgy. But there's no built-in formula in Excel. Other workarounds without VBA are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15144816/batch-string-concatenation-in-excel) and [there](http://chandoo.org/wp/2014/01/13/combine-text-values-quick-tip/), just in case.

By the way, Google Spreadsheet provides all of these as built-in functions. Just one line.

```
=join(";"&char(10), filter(unique(A2:A7), not(isblank(unique(A2:A7)))))&";"
```

Comment: Don't know if it was a typo or visual metaphor but bonus points for **ulgy**.

Comment: If this was my task in office, i'd do it with Google Spreadsheet.

Comment: Ahhhh it's a typo... should I fix it? :(

Comment: No, it is perfect just as it is. The basic problem is that the OP specified that the source as all in a single cell. (*Source list (one value - one cell)*)

Answer (score 0):

Use a static dictionary object in a user defined functiuon (aka UDF) and overwrite any duplicates.

```
Option Explicit

Function udfUniqueList(str As String, _
                       delim As String, _
                       Optional cs As Boolean = False)
    Dim a As Long, arr As Variant
    Static dict As Object
                      
    If dict Is Nothing Then
        Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    End If
    dict.RemoveAll
    dict.CompareMode = IIf(cs, vbBinaryCompare, vbTextCompare)
    
    arr = Split(str, Chr(10))
    For a = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        dict.Item(arr(a)) = a
    Next a
    
    udfUniqueList = Join(dict.keys, delim) & delim

End Function
```

A static object is best for functions that will be copied down a long column as the object does not have to be recreated for repetitious use.

[image]

Remember to turn 'wrap text' on in the destination cell.