# Making a list from range in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

In original column I have years in range(s). Like

```
1865–1868
```

How do I transform it to comma separated list? Like:

```
1865, 1866, 1867, 1868
```

The current data format is TEXT. And I plan to change it to DATE.

NOTE: The original cell often consists mixed form. Like "1865–1868, 1870"

Comment: You could adapt this VBA approach to your specific use case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15144816/batch-string-concatenation-in-excel/15145268#15145268

Comment: How can you set a cell with multiple years in them to DATE, you would need to split each year to a seperate cell.

Comment: Not sure if it's intentional, but that's not a `-` between those dates, that's a different symbol `–` , perhaps an *em-dash*.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
Public Function CSVList(rng As Range) As String
    Dim r As Range, ary1, ary2
    For Each r In rng
        v = r.Text
        If InStr(1, v, "-") = 0 Then
            CSVList = CSVList & "," & v
        Else
            ary = Split(v, "-")
                For i = CLng(ary(0)) To CLng(ary(1))
                    CSVList = CSVList & "," & CStr(i)
                Next i
        End If
    Next r
    CSVList = Mid(CSVList, 2)
End Function
```

[image]

or:

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

This UDF treats any non-numeral as a separator:

```
Public Function CSVList2(rng As Range) As String
    Dim r As Range, ary1, ary2, L As Long, i As Long, C As String
    For Each r In rng
        v = r.Text
        L = Len(v)
        C = ""
        For i = 1 To L
            If Not Mid(v, i, 1) Like "[0-9]" Then C = Mid(v, i, 1)
        Next i

        If C = "" Then
            CSVList2 = CSVList2 & "," & v
        Else
            ary = Split(v, C)
                For i = CLng(ary(0)) To CLng(ary(1))
                    CSVList2 = CSVList2 & "," & CStr(i)
                Next i
        End If
    Next r
    CSVList2 = Mid(CSVList2, 2)
End Function
```

Comment: @Vyach - Not sure if it's intentional, but that's not a `-` between those dates, that's a different symbol `–` , perhaps an *em-dash*.  To make Gary's code work you'll need to change that either in the code or on your end (unless it was just a typo).

Comment: @ashleedawg  or the code could easily be changed to treat **any** non-numeric single character as the separator.

Comment: @ashleedawg  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Wow, this is magic!
It doesn't handle a cell like "1865-1868, 1870, 1880", but I'll split such cells into multiple by ","
Thanks a lot!